# 'HiveContext' object has no attribute 'jsonRDD' Spark 2.1.1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a begginner in Spark. I am following a video course on PySpark.
I am trying to convert a json string into dataframe using below code.

```
    import pyspark as ps
    from pyspark.sql import HiveContext # to interface dataframe API

    sc = ps.SparkContext()
    hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

    # some code ....  and build meals_json
    meals_json.take(1) # below is output of this code
    #['{"meal_id": 1, "dt": "2013-01-01", "type": "french", "price": 10}']
    # some more code

    meals_dataframe = hive_context.jsonRDD(meals_json)
    meals_dataframe.first()
```

while tring to run last line, I am getting below error.

```
    AttributeError     Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-43e4f3006ac3> in <module>()
    ----> 1 meals_dataframe = hive_context.jsonRDD(meals_json)
          2 meals_dataframe.first()

    AttributeError: 'HiveContext' object has no attribute 'jsonRDD'
```

I searched the web, I am not able to find any resource where this problem is discussed. I am running this code using Spark 2.1.1 on jupyter notebook with Python 3.5.

From the documentation, I am able to see that jsonRDD is do inherited from **class org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext**. I am not quite sure, what could be the reason.
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlContext.jsonRDD` is [deprecated](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#jsonRDD(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD)). As of 1.4.0 it has been replaced by `read().json()`. I have included an example below that works on Spark 2.1.1

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, StringType

r = [{'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}, 
       {'a': 'aaaa','b': 'bbbb','c': 'cccc','d': 'dddd'}] 
r = [json.dumps(d) for d in r] 

# known schema 
schema = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schema] 
schema = StructType(fields) 

rdd = sc.parallelize(r) 
df = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rdd)
df.collect()
```

This gives the following output on Spark 2.1.1:

```
[Row(a=u'aaa', b=u'bbb', c=u'ccc', d=None),
 Row(a=u'aaaa', b=u'bbbb', c=u'cccc', d=u'dddd')]
```

Please note that the first part of this snippet is heavily inspired by [this question](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/jsonRDD-in-spark-2-td27329.html) on the Apache Spark user list

Comment: Thanks for your effort. As suggested by you, I just replaced the hive_context.jsonRDD(meals_json) call with hive_context.read.json(meals_json) and it worked!